# Problemas con hilos en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, hilos

tengo este codigo de c# donde utilizo un hilo para controlar la fecha pero al momento de correr el programa me sale el error 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control del label

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Thread hilo1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mostrar1));
        hilo1.Start();
        hilo1.Join();

    }
public void mostrar1()
    {
        string a = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        label1.Text = a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder a elementos del main thread como es el label desde un método asíncrono, utiliza Async y Await 
https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/async-y-await-en-c-como-manejar-asincronismo-en-net-de-manera-facil.aspx